# Evaluation of user-based collaborative filtering K-Nearest Neighbor Algorithm

Tags: recommendation-engine, nearest-neighbor, collaborative-filtering

I was trying to find evaluation mechanisms of collaborative K-Nearest neighbor algorithm, but i am confused how can I evaluate this algorithm. How can I be sure that the recommendation done by this algorithm is correct or good. Actually I have also developed an algorithm that i want to compare with it. but i am not sure how can i compare and evaluate both of them. The data set used by me is of movie lens.

your people help on evaluating this recomender system will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating recommender systems is a large concern of its research and industry communities. Look at "Evaluating collaborative filtering recommender systems", a Herlocker et al paper. The people who publish MovieLens data (the GroupLens research lab at the University of Minnesota) also publish many papers on recsys topics, and the PDFs are often free at http://grouplens.org/publications/.

Check out https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=evaluating+recommender+systems.

In short, you should use a method that hides some data. You will train your model on a portion of the data (called "training data") and test on the remainder of the data that your model has never seen before. There's a formal way to do this called cross-validation, but the general concept of visible training data versus hidden test data is the most important.

I also recommend https://www.coursera.org/learn/recommender-systems, a Coursera course on recommender systems taught by GroupLens folks. In that course you'll learn to use LensKit, a recommender systems framework in Java that includes a large evaluation suite. Even if you don't take the course, LensKit may be just what you want.